# I am trying to print a few key lines from a directory of like files using line.split('\n) --> not recognizing lines

Tags: python

So this input file already has line breaks. It's the natural setting in which it's created. When I attempt to identify certain lines so that I can go back and call the values from said lines i get,

```
name = line[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any thoughts? I know there has to be an easy solution as this is fairly basic but I have sifted through every entry on splitting and splitting with ('\n') and nothing has worked. Any help from you folks would be greatly appreciated!

-Ut prosim

**Input**:

```
    ID  rpmI_bact
    AC  TIGR00001
    DE  ribosomal protein L35
```

---

**Script**

```
for i in info.readlines():

    line = i.split('\n')
    id_hit = line[0]
    ac = line[1]
    name = line[2]

    print(name)
```

---

**Error**

```
name = line[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: it worked for me..  maybe you need to check for a carriage return instead `\r` ??

Comment: I tried that as well. It could just be an input_path issue if that snippet worked for you

Comment: Yessir. Its a 4kb file and the only info needed are what would be those first 3 lines. I have the script set up to run through an entire directory of like files though

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you do `readlines`, you will get back a list of **all** the lines your file, which will probably look something like this:

```
['    ID  rpmI_bact', '    AC  TIGR00001', '    DE  ribosomal protein L35']
```

If you take one of these values *and then* try to split on newlines, you won't get anything split:

```
'    ID  rpmI_bact'.split('\n')
['    ID  rpmI_bact']
```

Notice that the return value is a list with *one* element, so that's why you get your `IndexError`.

Now, it seems like you want to take each line and split on whitespace? If so, the way to do that is to use `split(' ')`, but this is going to give you potentially unreliable content back:

```
In [8]: for line in lines:
   ...:     print(line.split(' '))
   ...:     
['', '', '', '', 'ID', '', 'rpmI_bact']
['', '', '', '', 'AC', '', 'TIGR00001']
['', '', '', '', 'DE', '', 'ribosomal', 'protein', 'L35']
```

Notice how it's not obvious where the "content" is? We can solve this in a few ways. One is to introduce regexes, while the other way is to simply take the values that are not empty strings (note that empty strings in Python are `False`y values):

```
In [9]: bool("")
Out[9]: False
In [10]: for line in lines:
    ...:     print([elem for elem in line.split(' ') if elem])
    ...:     
['ID', 'rpmI_bact']
['AC', 'TIGR00001']
['DE', 'ribosomal', 'protein', 'L35']
```

Now you have to figure out what you want to do with those lists. I didn't really get that from the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably consider just making it a dictionary. Then you can query it by the 2 letter key. No need for the `.readlines()` either.

```
d = dict(line.strip().split('  ', 2) for line in info)
```

That should give you a dictionary looking like

```
{'AC': 'TIGR00001', 'DE': 'ribosomal protein L35', 'ID': 'rpmI_bact'}
```

Then you can just access the ID you're interested in

```
name = d['DE']
```

Comment: Oh damn! Thank you man. That is exactly was i was looking for!

Comment: Glad it helped :)